# signal() return type

Tags: c, unix, signals

I'm studying signal handling and I have a question about the return of signal:

```
void (*sighandler_t)(int);
```

I know it is a pointer to the previous function of the signal handler, but I don't know what the parameter "(int)" means.

Thank you very much!

Comment: As an aside, note that `sighandler_t` is not a standard type name and should never be used in code. It's unsafe because you can't rely on it existing, but you also can't define it yourself since the system headers might define it. Instead, always either write out the full type or define your own name for it like `my_sighandler`.

Answer (score 4):

The `int` parameter to a signal handler is the number of the signal which caused that handler to be called. This is useful if you have more than one signal connected to the same signal handler function.

Answer (score 2):

`(int)` is part of the type; the `sighandler_t` type is a pointer to a function that returns `void` and take an `int` as a parameter.

Answer (score 1):

A signal handler function has the signature you posted.  When your program receives a signal, he system calls your signal handler and sends it the signal to be handled as a parameter, so you could have a common handler for multiple signal types, for example.

Answer (score 0):

That's not exactly a pointer to the previous function. It's a declaration of a type of function pointer.

This pointer will work for any function with a void return type and an int parameter.

read more about how this syntax works here

http://www.cprogramming.com/tutorial/function-pointers.html